# Windows 2008 Group Policy Mapped Drives - Unmap

Tags: group-policy

I seem to be missing something?
I have a policy that seems to mapping drives, which I cannot find the policy, I've checked event viewer on local pc and cant see the policy.

On AD "Group Policy Results" their is no sign of it, I even created a "Remove Mapped Policy", which does not work, is something cached some where else?

[image]

Comment: Have you checked for logon scripts and the mapped home drive AD attribute?

Comment: checked login scripts, mapped home drive attribute? where would I check that?

Comment: Login scripts may be triggered in a multitude of ways, but the most common are through one or more GPOs and/or through ADUC User Properties (where you will also find the home drive mapping).

Comment: Yeap found it, Thank you, so many places to look and forget about...